# Cookie accessible with GET requests but not with PUT or POST requests

Tags: express, cookies, axios, cross-domain

I'm using React for the front-end, an Express API for our back-end, and I'm experiencing an issue with accessing our cookie with Axios' PUT or POST requests.

On Postman, i need to declare the cookie i need to make my front-end authorized on connecting to my API.
I'm doing it like this on Postman's interface :

[Example of passing cookie in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtekD.png)

And when i'm calling my API's requests, on Postman, with the cookie set it works and looks like this in the Postman's code snippet :

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "attributes": {
    "test": test
  }
});

var config = {
  method: 'put',
  url: 'APIurl/test',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'Bearer myPersonnalToken',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cookie': 'key=theCookieINeedToGetInMyAxiosRequest'
  },
  data: data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Ok so here it is working on Postman, time to make it real on my app with Axios, like this in my front-end :

```
var url = 'APIurl/test'
var data = { 
    test: test
}
var config = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer " + myPersonnalToken,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    withCredentials: true,
}

axios.put(url, JSON.stringify(data), config)
.then(res => {
    console.log(res)
    ...
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    ...
})
```

And knowing it's cross-domain, like this in my back-end :

```
const corsOptions = {
  // I tried with * to see if I mispelled the origin, but no
  origin: theOriginIWant,
  credentials: true
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

As I read a hundred times, {withCredentials: true} should be enough to pass my cookie in my request, and my CORS options look great to me.

But when I launch my app and click the button which calls the request, this is what my devtools Network looks like :

```
General
  Request URL: APIurl/test
  Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Request Headers
  Accept: application/json
  Authorization: Bearer myPersonnelToken
  Content-Type: application/json
  Referer: myAppUrl
  sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
  sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36

Request Payload
  test=test
```

As you can see, my cookie is missing...
A 401 error is thrown because I cannot access the API without the cookie, with the informations below :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'APIurl/test' from origin 'myAppUrl' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I tried everything i saw on the web, but nothing worked for me, i just can't pass the cookie i want to my PUT or POST requests, which throws an error.
I really don't understand why GET requests work, but not POST or PUT ones...

Any idea of how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance,

Hugo GB

Comment: The error you observe has got nothing to do with cookies, but with a failed preflight request. (Preflight requests are unnecessary for most GET requests, that's why these work.)
Where does the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: myAppUrl` header in your request come from? I don't understand what purpose that should serve.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen excuse my idiocy, i forgot to change that when i edited my post because i succeeded in making my GET request works (it wasn't working initially).
There is no "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: myAppUrl" for my PUT requests.

Comment: Where in your middleware sequence do you do `app.use(cors(corsOptions))`? Could it be that the preflight request (which is always made *without* credentials) fails at an earlier middleware already? It works for me if `cors(corsOptions)` is the first middleware to be executed.

Comment: In my middleware, i do it at the beginning.
I have a server.js file where i define my server's options, and my swagger.
My `app.use(cors(corsOptions))` is defined right after my imports, and juste before the other `app.use(...)` and my swagger's options.
It just looks like the server don't want me to send the PUT request because i cannot send the cookie with it, so I'm not authorized connecting to it and i don't know how to send the cookie...